# Setting Couchbase documents to expire based on tow configration

Tags: java, session, couchbase, bucket

I am using Couchbase server for session management with Java SDK client, I have one bucket for session storage.

Currently I am using Time to Live on each document to set expiration time for each session. I have a new requirement where I need to set the session to expire after 120 second but if the session is updated (touched) it will be extended for another 120 seconds, after 24 hours the session should be forced to expire.

How can I configure all Bucket documents to expire (after 24 hours) and keep current session document to expire after 120 seconds?

Comment: touch and other operations (in the SDKs) can update the expiry, which would work for your 120sec requirement. For the 24h hard limit, maybe you can store the creation datetime in your document and each time you touch, you also check if it's been created more than 24h ago?

Comment: Thanks, that's good work around, however if there is some configuration on Bucket level to force removal of sessions , it will be safer I think

Comment: as far as I know there is not. Only one expiration timestamp exist, at the document level (in document metadata, and note that even if you set expiration as a delay, couchbase stores it as a timestamp)

Comment: Thanks Simon , I think your solution will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments I was going to simply suggest setting a TTL for a long period of time. Would that not work?

EDIT:  I missed the spirit of the question. No, it would not work for what you're trying to do. I think you could set a TTL attribute in the json doc itself and enforce an expiry at the application level by checking this particular attribute in conjunction with setting a Couchbase TTL on the doc.

EDIT 2: Ok, I re-read Simon's reply. You got it. :)